# How create Regex Match between four delimiters

Tags: java, android, regex

```
String name="[COLOR dxvx]yyyy[/COLOR]"
String name="[COLOR dvvx]tttt[/COLOR]"
```

I need to get string yyyy that is between [COLOR dxvx] and [/COLOR] how can do this using regular expression in Java

noted inside [COLOR dxvx] next to COLOR word also changing

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try direct match with:

```
(?<=])[^]]+(?=\\[/COLOR)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sV2oJ4/1)

Implementation in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] strings = {"String name=\"[COLOR dxvx]yyyy[/COLOR]\"",
            "String name=\"[COLOR dvvx]tttt[/COLOR]\""};

    for(String string : strings) {
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=])[^]]+(?=\\[/COLOR)").matcher(string);
        if(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }

    }
}
```

with output:

```
yyyy
tttt
```

Answer (score 3):

Use capturing group.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[COLOR\\s+dxvx\\](.*?)\\[/COLOR\\]").matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
 }
```

Comment: thanx for your reply.in side this [COLOR dxvx], next to "COLOR" world is not defined. that also changing..

Comment: try `"\\[COLOR\\s+\\w+\\](.*?)\\[/COLOR\\]"`